# Angular ui modal scope inheritance

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller, modal-dialog

I know that the question is simple and may be boring for most of you, but I am newbie in Angular so help me to understand please.
What is the relation between angular ui modal scope and scope of that template where the modal is being called? And how to update the scope data of that page after closing the modal.

Comment: You're refering to AngularUI Bootstrap Modal?

Comment: Yes, Angular UI Bootstrap Modal

Comment: Please share code on how you initiate the modal